# C# Invoke Powershell with pre-created object

Tags: c#, powershell, invoke

I've just started out with PS and are writing some C# classes which I need to test from within PS.

**Please note that these classes are NOT CmdLets.**

I want to do something like this:

```
var myCustomObj = new CustomObj { Message = "Hello world" };

var ps = Powershell.Create();

ps.AddCommand("Import-Module").AddParameter("Assembly", "MyCustomAsm");
ps.AddCommand("myCustomObj.Run()").AddParameter(myCustomObj);

foreach(string str in ps.AddCommand("Out-String").Invoke<string>()) 
        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Where I invoke Run() on the object handed to PS, the result would be a printout "Hello world".

But i'm not even sure that this is possible (might be for security reasons).

I figure I've got 2 options:

1. **Either this is possible. If so please help me :) ?**
2. **I will have to generate the script file based on my existing object and the do an "AddScript(...)" to have ps execute it.**

Any pointers to get me started would be nice :).

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
        var objs= new PSDataCollection<CustomObj> {obj};

        using (var ps = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("objList", objs);
            ps.AddScript(@"$objList| ForEach { $_.Run()}");
            ps.AddCommand("Out-String");
            var output = ps.Invoke();

            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var obj in output)
            {
                stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
            }

            var result = stringBuilder.ToString().Trim();

            //Evaluate result.
        }
```